# Turn a character array into a string?

Tags: arrays, string, mips

I'm looking for a method to convert a character array into a string. Currently, I have this character array:

```
hexVal: .word 4 {contains '0', 'x', '8', '0'}
```

And I'm looking to use this array to turn some register into a string "0x80". At first, I tried the load word instruction, to grab the four bytes and store them in a register:

```
lw $t0, hexVal
```

But that did not work as nicely as I had hoped. Printing the resulting register $t0 yields an output of 0. I can access the various different characters using indexing and print them like this:

```
addi $t1, $zero, 0              # use $t1 as our index, starting at 0
while:
     beq $t1, 3, exit           # if $t1 = 3, exit
     lb $t0, hexVal($t1)        # grab the byte at the index
     li $v0, 11                 # 11 = character print
     la $a0, $t0
     syscall                    # print the character at $t0
     addi $t1, $t1, 1           # increment index by 1
     j while
exit:
     # do something else
```

This will output "0x80". However, for a program I'm working on, I need to be able to store the ASCII string "0x80" in a register. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: _"Printing the resulting register $t0 yields an output of 0"_ There's no system call that I'm aware of that interprets the contents of register as a four-character string and prints it. So how exactly _did_ you attempt to print it?

Comment: You pose a good question, because I was wondering the same thing when I first thought about trying this. At first I tried printing as a string, which caused a runtime error. The only syscall that would actually produce an output was syscall 11, so it makes sense that it only prints one character, and that character is the first in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between a character array and a string is that the string is terminated by a '\0'.

So you can put a '\0' at the end of hexval (that should a size 5 array).
If it is not possible, create a new array and copy the chars to it.

When you have a string, you can use syscall 4 to print it.

By the way, `hexVal` was not a char array, but a word array, and your code was broken.

```
hexVal: .byte 4 {contains '0', 'x', '8', '0'}
hexstr: .byte 5

.text
    addi  $t0,zero,4 # i=4
    li $t1,hexVal
    li $t2,hexstr
copy:
    # copy hexval[i] to hexstr[i]
    lb $t3, 0($t1)
    sb $t3, 0($t2)
    # increments
    addi $t0,-1
    addi $t1,1
    addi $t2,1
    beq $t0,zero, copy
    nop
end:
    sb zero,0($t2) # add '\0' at the end of hexStr
    # then print hexStr a string with syscall 4
    addi $v0, zero, 4 
    li $a0, hexStr
    syscall
```

Comment: Seems to have done the trick! Thanks for your insight Alain, I really appreciate it! :)